# Hamiltonian Cycle - graph with specific conditions

Tags: graph, hamiltonian-cycle

I'm trying to do a lot of programming exercises to understand concepts and get hands-on experience practice by tackling them.

I've stumbled upon an exercise that gives a set of conditions as to how the graph is like and requires you to find out whether or not a **Hamiltonian cycle** is possible or not, and if there is, print out of one the possibilities.

Since the exercise is in my native language, I've translated it as best as I could and it goes as follows:

Let there be a graphic **G=(V,E)**, having the number of vertices **V** and the number of edges **E**. We will notate **N(v)** as the set of vertices connected to v. The number of adjacent vertices of a vertex is called rank and we notate it with **rank(v)**.

We say that the graphic G is weird if it is conex and for every vertex of the graph the next conditions are met:

1. **Rank(v)>=2**
2. If **rank(v)=2** then the other two vertices are not connected with one another by an edge.
3. If **rank(v)>2** then the set of adjacent vertices of **v** there exists a vertex **u ( u ∈ N(v) )**, so the following properties are true:
   I. **Rank(u)=2** AND II. Every other two distinct vertices of the adjacent vertices of **v**, **(w1,w2 ∈ N(v)-{u} )** are connected to one another, so **(w1,w2) ∈ E**.

Every graph required to solve is to be considered a "weird" graph.

How does one tackle this problem? You need to drastically minimize computation time with the help of the conditions, but I can't think of a trick/pattern to search the Hamiltonian cycle with them as of yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make the question a programming one, by showing some effort in testing with some program and results expected vs obtained.

Comment: I would gladly do so, but I don't have the slightest clue on how to interpret the third condition into code to find a Hamiltonian cycle. I would implement some type of backtracking, but I expect that to fail due to the insane computation it requires when the cycle is not possible in the graph. Tried drawing some graphs out and figuring out a pattern, but to no avail.